# npm build - not working, "npm-build.html not found"

Tags: node.js, npm

it's looking for a file that is no longer there, "npm build" not working

```
PS C:\Users\simon\Desktop\3-Projects\1-Coding\simon\simon> npm build
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: cmd.exe /c start "" file://C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\npm\docs\output\commands\npm-build.html
npm ERR! The system cannot find the file file://C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module\npm\docs\output\commands\npm-build.html.
```

package.json                                                                 .

```
{
  "name": "simon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event

": "^7.2.1",
    "build": "^0.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "npm": "^7.5.6",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.26.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

It says that a file is missing in the above directory, how to run a "npm build".

Comment: Please edit your question with the build script from package.json.

Comment: @LoganDevine ive added my package.json

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `npm run build` instead of `npm build`. `npm build` compiles packages, causing this error.

Only `start` and `test` are exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with run. Only start and test don’t need run
npm run build